# Rails Turbo How do I render a partial when clicked?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, renderpartial, hotwire-rails, turbo, stimulus-rails

I have a Ruby on Rails application with a popup currently set to show and hide through Turbo Toggle. However, I've noticed that this approach impacts the page loading speed.

To reduce the load times of the parent page I was thinking about rendering the tab only when clicked.

`.div{ "data-controller": "toggle" } %div.{"data-action": "click->toggle#toggle touch->toggle#toggle"} = link_to 'Customers' = render "customers"`

Comment: Could you please share your stimulus-controller? You would have to load the customer-div (?) within the toggle-method. Alternativly you could use eager-loading of frames like this: https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/frames#eager-loading-frames - which will be a lot easier and should make the page-loading quicker

Comment: Let me explain. I have a page where more than one popup will be shown on click(through toggle). And also has some ruby code under the popups. So I just want the popups partial will render/load only when a user clicks on the toggle link.

Comment: So how does your stimulus-controller look so far? What did you already try?

Comment: stimulus-controller working fine. I tried to solve the issue through turbo lazy-loading but still did not succeed.
https://turbo.hotwired.dev/reference/frames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, let's try figure out what could be helpful for you. Basically you have three options

1. Eager-loading of frames for a better performance
2. Using Turbo-Frames for navigation
3. Using Stimulus (as you are already using it)

Either way, you have to provide a separate method and a view for rendering the customers-part - something like 'customer/:id'

For the first two options to work you have to make sure, that your customer-layout (the sub-layout) includes the turbo-frames tag. Using Rails you can do:

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag(@customer) do %>
  <%= #all of your customer-stuff %>
<% end %>
```

which renders into

```
 <turbo-frame id="customer_1">all of your customer-stuff</turbo-frame>
```

For the first option, the eager-loading of Frames is done this way:

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag @customer, src: customer_path(@customer) %>
```

For the second, it's just

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag @customer %>
```

Just make sure that you create the turbe-frame tag the same way as in your sublayout, and the replacement should happen automatically.

For the third option you could fetch the sub-page /customer/:id and replace the div for yourself. Have a look at https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/handbook/working-with-external-resources for a starting example.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I have successfully implemented this issue through the turbo lazy-loading.